# How do i resolve the CSS stylesheet reference conflict? Is localization possible?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a html webpage code that relies on 2 stylesheets. I am guessing that they are conflicting with each other because when i remove one of them, the other one works and vice versa.

the first stylesheet is used from a specific drop down menu for my nav bar whereas the 2nd one helps to input little icons in my webpage.

Is there any way to localize the style sheets or to make this code work? I am new to this. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Have you tried including bootstrap first, then fontawesome?

Comment: Both should not conflict each other because fontawesome is basically an icon library while bootstrap is a CSS framework. Both have separate prefixes in their classes. Try changing the order or check if bootstrap.min.css has any code related to fontawesome

Comment: In your browser console, when you select an element with dev tools you can do it easy by click to an element html who got a conflict and show witch property is taken from witch files.css or from the the inline css attribute style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement all scripts and css related to those libraries:
**For bootstrap you can see the "Getting Started" section**
[here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/)

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**The same for font-awesome** [here](http://fontawesome.io/get-started/)